# Как получить найденный фрагмент с помощью оператора LIKE

Tags: javascript, php, sql

Есть ли возможность получить фрагмент, который нашел оператор LIKE?

Например в бд запись - `email778547@mail.ru`

Запрос - `LIKE %__7@mail.ru%`

Нижнее подчеркивание заменяет собой любой символ, соответственно будет найден этот фрагмент - `547@mail.ru`

Есть ли возможность получить этот фрагмент?

Если нет - какая есть возможность это получить?

Требуется сделать выделение найденного текста, пытался сделать это чисто на JS, но не вышло. Возможно есть какая-то готовая библиотека для поиска на JS или на PHP - будет проводиться аналогичный LIKE поиск и выдаваться результат.

Comment: а что не вышло на JS ? вам искомый паттерн надо заменить на регулярку, заменив `_` на `.`

Comment: "пытался сделать это чисто на JS, но не вышло", а приложите Вашу попытку.

Comment: @teran, можно какой-то пример, чтобы было более ясное понимание? С JS не так сильно знаком

Comment: @another_login, https://codepen.io/dimarrr/pen/oNdEOdQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

на пхп что-то подобное может быть

```
$txt = "some text email778547@mail.ru test email778547@mail.ru test2";
$like = "__7@mail.ru";
$pattern = str_replace('_', '.', preg_quote($like));

$result = preg_replace("/$pattern/", '<mark>$0</mark>', $txt);

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 1):

Из БД этот фрагмент, на сколько я знаю, получить нельзя.
Ниже примерный подход, как вы можете это реализовать у себя. Собственно сам язык,php или js, тут не важен. Где формируете строку для отображения пользователю, там и делайте.

Я показываю не решение, а идею, а уже как реализовывать это, решайте сами

```
// Запишем искомое в виде переменных
const fixLike '7@mail.ru'; // Точный текст
const append = '__'; // Любые символы
// Формируете из них запрос в БД
const sqlQuery = `select email from table where email like '%${append}${fixLike}%'`;
// Полученный ответ парсите
dataFromDB.forEach((mail) => {
    const start = mail.indexOf(fixLike);
    const find = mail.slice(start - append.length, start + fixLike.length)
    console.log(find); // Показывает что найдено

    const strArr = mail.split(find);
    // Тут конечно надо предусмотреть различные варианты
    // Количество элементов  в массиве может быть много и после первого элемента, остальные элементы надо обратно склеить в строку
    // Для частного случая 'email' будет 1 элемент в массиве
    console.log(strArr[0] + '<b>' + find + '</b>' + strArr[1]); // Строка для рендера
})
```

Comment: сам принцип +- понятнет, но ведь запрос может быть такого формата - `_123__@___.ru`. LIKE в php его отработает и выведет результаты, а как найти такой же фрагмент на JS?

Comment: @DimaRRR изменить `_123_0___.ru` на `.123.0...\.ru` и искать по регулярному выражению

Comment: @teran, 1. Для чего требуется эта замена? 2. Может есть какое-то готовое регулярное выражение?

Comment: потому что в sql-like символ `_` соответствует любому, а в регулярках точка соответствует любому. Исходную точку (да и в целом остальные управляющие последовательности) надо экранировать, а подчеркивания перевести в формат регулярок.

Comment: @teran, Всё, разобрался. А я там нагородил... Спасибо!